# Get the offset for a specific time and timezone in python

Tags: python, timezone-offset

I need a function that will return the offset for a specific timezone at a specific moment. I have the timezone in a string variable in the format `America/Los_Angeles` and I have the date in format `2014-12-01`

The offset needs to be DST sensitive, meaning that for Los Angeles, it should return -07 during summer and -08 during winter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the string into a timezone object with [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
```

Convert the date to a `datetime` object with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now the hour offset can be derived:

```
offset = int(tz.utcoffset(dt).total_seconds() / 3600.0)
```